# linq changing order of columns

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IQueryable that's returned from a query.

The columns are `Article, Id, Lot`.

What's a simple linq way to have the columns `Id, Article, Lot`.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` of what type `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I found is

```
from t in table 
select new{ Id = t.Id, Article = t.Article, Lot = t.Lot }
```

as @driis says order doesnt matter.

Comment: because you have to wait 3min before you can accept; be patient:)

Answer (score 5):

You are working with objects that have named properties corresponding to the columns in the database. **The order shouldn't matter**.

Comment: I don't control the query, I get the result of the query in a queryable and I'm looking to change the order from within the resulting object.